# Nested Model saving/syncing with Sencha Touch 2 with 1 request

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to save() a parent model and have it also send across the associated data in a nested JSON format, just like how it's received?

So my data structure is like this:

Events hasOne organiser
Events hasMany attendees

```
events: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Birthday Party',
    organiser: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jill'
    },
    attendees: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bob'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Jill'
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I could just do events.save() and it would also include the hasOne and hasMany data nested, so I don't have to make another 2 requests to get the data to the server?

Thanks, Dominic

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's driving me crazy...

Comment: Nope it's not yet possible but the Sencha team have mentioned they want to implement it at some point. You just have to save each items in your nested data manually.